# Using MSAL in CloudShell

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-account

I've validated the MSAL auth path using the desktop PowerShell 5.1 and 7.0 applications. However, all of the authentication paths which worked on the desktop are not working in CloudShell -

```
PS /home/michael/CSTest/0.0.2/MicrosoftTeams> connect-microsoftteams
Connect-MicrosoftTeams: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to open a web page using xdg-open. See inner exception for details. Possible causes for this error are: xdg-open is not installed or it cannot find a way to open an url - make sure you can open a web page by invoking from a terminal: xdg-open https://www.bing.com )
Connect-MicrosoftTeams: Unable to open a web page using xdg-open. See inner exception for details. Possible causes for this error are: xdg-open is not installed or it cannot find a way to open an url - make sure you can open a web page by invoking from a terminal: xdg-open https://www.bing.com
Connect-MicrosoftTeams: No such file or directory
Connect-MicrosoftTeams: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to open a web page using xdg-open. See inner exception for details. Possible causes for this error are: xdg-open is not installed or it cannot find a way to open an url - make sure you can open a web page by invoking from a terminal: xdg-open https://www.bing.com )
PS /home/michael/CSTest/0.0.2/MicrosoftTeams> connect-microsoftteams -UseDeviceAuthentication
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code BRZPG2UNE to authenticate.
Connect-MicrosoftTeams: One or more errors occurred. (Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI) is not supported on this platform.)
Connect-MicrosoftTeams: Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI) is not supported on this platform.
Connect-MicrosoftTeams: One or more errors occurred. (Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI) is not supported on this platform.)
PS /home/michael/CSTest/0.0.2/MicrosoftTeams> connect-microsoftteams -AccountId miluong@microsoft.com
Connect-MicrosoftTeams: One or more errors occurred. (Federated service at https://msft.sts.microsoft.com/adfs/services/trust/13/windowstransport returned error: )
Connect-MicrosoftTeams: Federated service at https://msft.sts.microsoft.com/adfs/services/trust/13/windowstransport returned error:
Connect-MicrosoftTeams: Federated service at https://msft.sts.microsoft.com/adfs/services/trust/13/windowstransport returned error:
Connect-MicrosoftTeams: One or more errors occurred. (Federated service at https://msft.sts.microsoft.com/adfs/services/trust/13/windowstransport returned error: )
```

- How do I enable support for managed identity?
- How do I get interactive auth flow to work without xdg-open? Currently CloudShell does not install xdg-open
- Is there a recommended path to try to acquire a token without DPAPI? CloudShell works in a Linux environment and DPAPI only supports Windows.
- Do you know of any PS modules which use MSAL that are working in CloudShell?

Answer (score 0):

1. xdg-open does not work and is not planned to be supported in CloudShell
2. The DPAPI error was because I was trying to protect the token by encrypting it at rest
3. Integrated Windows Authentication is not a supported workflow in CloudShell because it's a Linux based environment.